Getting error "[class] and [className] bindings cannot be used on the same element simultaneously" after updating from Angular 8 to Angular 9
I working on a huge project with thousands of html elements that contains both class attribute and multiple class bindings simultaneously. I am updating the angular version from 8.2 to 9
If I start now replacing the class bindings with the ngClass then it will take me a few weeks to replace all the references.
Please help me with any command which can resolve this issue.
Following is the error I got after compilation:-
ERROR in Error: [class] and [className] bindings cannot be used on the same element simultaneously
at StylingBuilder.registerClassInput (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14096:27)
at StylingBuilder.registerInputBasedOnName (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14056:36)
at StylingBuilder.registerBoundInput (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14033:36)
at C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18176:57
at Array.forEach ()
at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.visitElement (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18175:28)
at Element.visit (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4442:28)
at visitAll (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4638:40)
at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.visitElement (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18348:13)
at Element.visit (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4442:28)
at visitAll (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4638:40)
at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.visitElement (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18348:13)
at Element.visit (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4442:28)
at visitAll (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4638:40)
at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17828:13)
at Object.compileComponentFromMetadata (C:\Users\VishakVashist\Documents\GitHub\RenovoUI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:19523:58)
